# Python: `TypeError` on multiplication

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to doing my coursework and I'm currently trying to produce a receipt of the products, here is the part of the coding which I think is the problem:

```
if ProductNumberStr==order:
        item_in_productslist=True
        print()
        print("PRODUCT FOUND:")
        print()
        print("Product Number: ",ProductNumberStr)
        print("Description: ",DescriptionStr)
        print("Price per item: ",price)
        print("Quantity of item ordered: ",quantity)
        print("Total cost of order: ",price*quantity)
        print()
        print("*************************************")
        print()
        ReceiptStr+=ProductNumberStr+" "+DescriptionStr+
                    " "+str(quantity)+" "+str(price)+" "+str(price)*str(quantity)
```

When I try to print the 'ReceiptStr', an error occurs, I've tried to fix it, but being a beginner, I can't seem to figure out how to fix the error.
This is what the error states:

> *ReceiptStr+=ProductNumberStr+" "+DescriptionStr+" "+str(quantity)+" "+str(price)+" "+str(price)*str(quantity) TypeError: can't multiply
>   sequence by non-int of type 'str'*

If anyone could help out, I'd be really grateful!

Comment: error is clear `str(price)*str(quantity)` how do you expect to multiply strings?

Comment: you cannot multiply 2 strings together (it makes no sense). Convert to string _after_ having multiplied the integers.

`str(price)*str(quantity)` => `str(price*quantity)`

Comment: @EdChum I appeciate the help but I don't really know anything about coding, I'm 15, never been taught my teacher, just been given videos of a guy writing up the code, sorry if I seem like an idiot but to me the error wasn't clear at all, but thanks again!

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Thanks for the help!

Comment: in those cases, it's better to decompose all operations and see which one has a problem. You can do this even if you don't have a clue of what's going on. Then you figure it out.

Comment: Jean-François Fabre  Thanks for the advice, I appreciate it, I'll keep that in mind next time, sorry for the inconvenience caused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably:

```
str(price*quantity)
```

str(x) is of type string, so there is no operation to multiply strings: str(x) * str(y). What you want to do, I think, is multiply de values and use the result as string. So, see the syntax above